# Is there a good library for cutting out people in a still photo?

Tags: image-processing

Are there any libraries, in any language, out there to help identify and grab the images of people in a still photo?  Something similar in effect to the way the Kinect can isolate users.

Thanks much!

Comment: No. It's a complicated problem that doesn't lend itself to simple solutions.

Comment: I am not sure why and what you are looking for but you could check image inpainting , in which you select a region of a picture to remove and give you a resulting image which will be as if that particular object in the image did not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends very much on the setup (e.g. simple bg. with decent lighting condition vs. random bg. with random lighting). If you can make life easier for yourself and isolate a few simpler use cases that would be great. Still there are other available method, look at the plethora of research around pedestrian detection for example.

One thing I did try and it works surprisingly well although computationally intensive is the Histogram of Gradient Orientations, implemented in [OpenCV as the HoG descriptor](http://experienceopencv.blogspot.com/2011/02/hog-descriptor.html). For a still photo this should produce decent results. You can have a look at the [OpenCV sample](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/c/peopledetect.cpp?rev=2314). I also recommend having a look at [Dramanan's excellent papers](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~dramanan/papers/people_chapter.pdf).

Long story short, thanks for years of inspiring research in computer vision, there are quite a few interesting options out there, it's up to how willing you are to go into detail. Still, regardless of how clever algorithms can be, I believe it's far more important to get a decent setup that allows simple and efficient solutions rather than complex solutions that try to cater for every possible situation. Goodluck!